How to get pyparsing to match "1 day" or "2 days" but fail "1 days" and "2 day"?
I'm trying to match a sentence fragment of the form "after 3 days" or "after 1 month". I want to be particular with the single and plural forms, so "1 day" is valid but "1 days" is not.
I have the following code which is nearly there but the first two entries in the failure tests don't fail. Any suggestions please that use syntactical notation as I'd like, if possible, to avoid a set_parse_action() that checks the numeric value against the unit's plurality.
from pyparsing import *

units = Keyword('days') ^ Keyword('months')
unit  = Keyword('day') ^ Keyword('month')

single = Literal('1') + unit
multi = Word(nums) + units

after = Keyword('after') + ( single ^ multi )

a = after.run_tests('''
    after 1 day
    after 2 days
    after 1 month
    after 2 months
    ''')

print('=============')

b = after.run_tests('''
    after 1 days
    after 2 day
    after 1day
    after 2days
    ''', failure_tests = True)

print('Success tests', 'passed' if a[0] else 'failed')
print('Failure tests', 'passed' if b[0] else 'failed')


To exercise correct handling of a leading 1 digit, I suggest adding "after 10 days" and "after 21 days" to the success tests and "after 10 day" and "after 21 day" to the failure tests.

And congratulations, you have asked the 1,000th pyparsing question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyparsing

Only the case after 1 days passes when it should fail, the other three cases fail as expected.
The issue is that the check multi = Word(nums) + units uses nums which includes 1, so even if your singular variant does not work, this one will. I looked up how nums is defined, apparently it is nums = '0123456789' (see here). Consequently you remove the 1. This works for me:
...
multi_nums = '023456789'  # nums excluding 1

single = Literal('1') + unit
multi = Word(multi_nums) + units
...

EDIT:
The above fails for double digits including 1, see comments. Fixed version as per comments:
single = Literal('1') + unit
multi = ~Keyword('1') + Word(nums) + units


You are on the right track, but this won't match "after 10 days". To reject a lone "1" with a plural, you could use a negative lookahead like this multi = ~Keyword("1") + Word(nums) + units (Keyword is required so that you only match a single "1", but not the first "1" of "10"), or a Regex like this multi = Regex(r"[1-9]\d+|[2-9]") + units.

@BruceH Made the edit.

Thanks aRTy and thanks Paul - I'm slowly getting  the hang of how your parser works.
